# Creating Javascript array via php

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

After spending an embarrassing number of hours on this, I still can't figure out an answer.   I have a Javascript/HTML program that has a large dynamic table in it with lots of buttons in the cells of the table.  I'd like to send the user's selections of buttons to a database when the user is finished with the page.   I will then use those in the receiving php program to display a graph.  I've got all of the values of the buttons into a Javascript array, so now I'd like to send the entire array and then use them as a Javascript array in the new program.  Every time I try this, I get no results.  Here is an example based on what I've found on stackoverflow: 
Sending program:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<script>
var ourObj={};
ourObj.data="4";
ourObj.arPoints = [{'x':1, 'y': 2},{'x': 2.3, 'y': 3.3},{'x': -1, 'y': -4}];
$.ajax({
   url: 'testb2.php',
   type: 'post',
   data: {"points" : JSON.stringify(ourObj)},
   success: function(data) {
        alert("success");
   }
});
</script>
</html>
```

Receiving php program:

```
<?php>
// Test if our data came through
echo "starting";
if (isset($_POST["points"])) {
    // Decode our JSON into PHP objects we can use
    $points = json_decode($_POST["points"]);
    // Access our object's data and array values.
    echo "Data is: " . $points->data . "<br>";
    echo "Point 1: " . $points->arPoints[0]->x . ", " . $points->arPoints[0]->y;
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "xxx";
    $password = "yyy";
    $dbname = "zzz";
    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if (!$conn) {
        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());    
    }
    $sql = "
        INSERT INTO FootprintAction(UserID, ActionValue, fpID)
        VALUES (?, ?, ?);
    ";
    if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql)) {
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "iss", $points->data, "1", "1");

        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    } else {
        //echo "no result from attempt to insert people into fpAction". "<br>";
        //echo $sql;
    }

}   
?>
```

What I get is a blank screen from the sending program with only an alert saying "success" (i.e., no answer from the receiving program) and no insertion into the database.

Can you suggest what I am doing wrong?  Or even better, is there a simple way using php to get a javascript array from a client-side program to a server-side program?   The array I'm trying to send is a set of string data, without labels; here's a row of the array:

```
actions[ 5] = new Array(    "Install Photovoltaic (Solar) Panels","6.33","1020","33121","0","25","149.8","0","0","0","1","1","Photovoltaic (solar) systems allow you to produce green electricity on your own rooftop.  Vendors often offer both purchase and lease options.   ","3","1.5","10","5.75","0");
```

I'd like to end up with a Javascript array in the receiving program identical to that in the sending program.
  Thanks!!!

Comment: Have you tried `console.log(data)` in your success handler? That'll print all of the stdout from your PHP script, letting you `echo` and `var_dump` the `$_POST` array to see what's going on.

Comment: OK, first of all, your `success` function inside your `$.ajax()` call is not doing anything to actually look at the `data` result that came back in the response.  In AJAX terms, any HTTP request that doesn't fail - e.g., a 500 Error - is a "success".  So it will trigger the success function.  That doesn't mean your call did anything close to what you wanted.  It just means that the call didn't bomb out.  And without looking at that `data` variable at all, you're just blindly using a simple JS alert to trigger the "success" alert.  So that "success" only means that the connection worked.